# multi thread is not closing though terminated

Tags: python, multithreading

For some reason, when the timeout is reached and the `except` is therefore executed, thread 2 is still "working", still expecting to get values from the user.  Even though the `closing_threads` function is entered.

Why can't I terminate the thread? Why is it still waiting for keyboard entry?
If I add `t2.join()` then execution hangs indefinitely.

```
def main():
    q2 = queue.Queue()
    q1 = queue.Queue()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=nothing, name='t1', args=(q1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_interrupt_from_user, name='t2', args=(q2,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    try:
        q2.get(timeout=4)
    except:
        ...

    closing_threads(t1, t2)


def closing_threads(t1, t2):
    print('closing the threads')
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print(t1.is_alive())
    print(t2.is_alive())

def get_interrupt_from_user(q) -> None:
    print('############ Thread 2 is starting!  ############')
    interrupt = False
    while not interrupt:
        print('use KeyboardInterrupt to stop the execution')
        try:
            input()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('KeyboardInterrupt exception took place')
        else:
            print('exit by KeyboardInterrupt!!!')
            interrupt = True
            print(f'interrupt took place = {interrupt}')
            q.put(interrupt)

def nothing(q) -> None:
    print('############ Thread 1 is starting!  ############')
```

Comment: `join` does not terminate threads.  It waits for them to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

the second thread is technically not working, nor terminated, it is in a suspended state by the operating system, it will be terminated when it returns from this suspended state.

when you call `input` the operating system suspends the thread, and waits for input, then when input is available it wakes the thread and sends it the user input ... problem is that during that time it cannot handle interrupts ... because it is not executing code.

one way you can solve this is to declare the thread as daemon and not join it, so it will be killed when the other python threads die.

```py
import queue
import threading

def main():
    q2 = queue.Queue()
    q1 = queue.Queue()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=nothing, name='t1', args=(q1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_interrupt_from_user, name='t2', args=(q2,),daemon=True)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    try:
        q2.get(timeout=4)
    except:
        ...

    closing_threads(t1, t2)


def closing_threads(t1, t2):
    print('closing the threads')
    t1.join()
    print(t1.is_alive())
    print(t2.is_alive())

def get_interrupt_from_user(q) -> None:
    print('############ Thread 2 is starting!  ############')
    interrupt = False
    while not interrupt:
        print('use KeyboardInterrupt to stop the execution')
        try:
            input()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('KeyboardInterrupt exception took place')
        else:
            print('exit by KeyboardInterrupt!!!')
            interrupt = True
            print(f'interrupt took place = {interrupt}')
            q.put(interrupt)

def nothing(q) -> None:
    print('############ Thread 1 is starting!  ############')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

other ways are sort of platform dependent and would involve summoning another processes that would signal the operating system to wake your thread up or terminate it and it gets messy really quick.

one last method is to use the `select` module on your stdin for this and create your own eventloop on the child thread, but this only works on linux.